# How to run a Django manage.py command (Django-background-tasks) after startup in Docker?

Tags: python, django, docker

I have a Django project which I'm using Docker and plan to deploy to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Based on these requirements, I need to run a manage.py command (namely 'process_tasks' from django-background-tasks) without human intervention.

If my understanding is correct, 'process_tasks' must be run otherwise the tasks will not be executed at the scheduled time.

I came up with the following solution to add in my docker-compose.yml.
The problem is I call my background task in 'urls' on server start and somehow this solution results in adding the task to the db twice. My objective is to run a background task everyday at a certain time.
Is there a simpler solution I'm missing?

```
  web:
    build: .
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db

  tasks:
    build: .
    command: python3 manage.py process_tasks
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    depends_on:
      - web
      - db
```

Answer (score 0):

```
web:
 build:
    context:./containerfolder


volumes:
  - .:/code
ports:
  - "8000:8000"
depends_on:
  - db
```

in-side your container docker file write your commands like python3 manage.py runserver and python3 manage.py process_tasks