# How to deploy Django application using Django-background-tasks on AWS beanstalk?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, background-task

I am using Django-background-tasks in my application, it worked fine for me on my local machine, I am trying to deploy the website to AWS elastic-beanstalk. I wanted to know how to mimic the 2 cmd prompt situation in windows( one with "python manage.py runserver"  and the other with "python manage.py process_tasks") in AWS. This will be a kind of parallel situation where both commands need to run simultaneously.

I tried adding the command as one of the container_commands in the config file in "./.ebextensions" but it didn't work (i consider AWS waits for such commands to end and it never ends, that's the case").

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53866093/how-to-run-a-django-manage-py-command-django-background-tasks-after-startup-in?

Comment: Ive also asked the question here - https://superuser.com/questions/1449339/how-to-deploy-django-application-using-django-background-tasks-on-aws-beanstalk